# Node Express 4 get header in middleware missing

Tags: json, node.js, express, content-type, middleware

I have a middleware function using Node's Express4 to log each request & response for debugging.  I use the res.json call in the request handler to send back JSON to the client for all but static files.  So I do not want to log the response for static files, but only the JSON responses.  I have the following code:

```
function logRequests(req, res, next) {
    // do logging (will show user name before authentication)
    logger.reqLog('IN  '+req.method+' '+req.url, req);

    var oldEnd   = res.end,
        oldWrite = res.write,
        chunks   = [];

    res.write = function(chunk) {
        chunks.push(chunk);
        oldWrite.apply(res, arguments);
    };

    res.end = function(chunk, encoding) {
        if(chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        }
        oldEnd.apply(res, arguments);

        // the content-type prints "undefined" in some cases
        // even though the browser shows it returned as "application/json"
        console.log('type='+res.get('content-type'));

        if(res.get('content-type') === 'application/json') {
            var body = Buffer.concat(chunks).toString('utf8');
            logger.info(body, req);
        }
        logger.reqLog('OUT '+req.method+' '+req.path, req);
    };
    next(); // make sure we go to the next routes and don't stop here
}
```

So why do some requests show the correct content type in the middleware meaning they also print the response fine and others do not?  All of them look good in the REST client when inspecting the returned headers.

EDIT: Some more info discovered tonight while trying to figure this out - if I append any character as a dummy request parameter, it logs the response type correctly:

```
http://localhost:8081/node/ionmed/api/logout?0   WORKS
```

where

```
http://localhost:8081/node/ionmed/api/logout     DOES NOT
```

Also, I can always get a response type logging in the middleware function if I replace the .json() call with .end() so this:

```
    res.json({ item: 'logout', success: true });
```

becomes:

```
    res.set('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.end({ item: 'logout', success: true });
```